# How to check if there is any new data in DB or update DbSet with new data using EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, ef-core-3.1

How can I check if there is any new data in Database using EF Core 3.1?
I like to check is some data was added/changed any another user since Context was created for my instance.

Best Regards!

Comment: Are you asking this because you want to prevent concurrency problems caused by two users editing the same data?

Comment: not really, you need to hit db or have the services updating data emit events that you can then use to update it but still hitting db will be involved.

Comment: how to hit it? recreate dbContext? We have apps that stay open for a long time. What I try to do is set up the refresh button to get the latest data from DB in case it changed since dbContext was created at the start of the app.

Comment: @KonradPsiukPG the question suggests you're misusing DbContext or consider it some kind of cache or in-memory copy of the database. It's not. It's meant to be short lived, used as a Unit-of-Work. It's meant to only track the changes you make to it, in a single *business* transaction. When you call `SaveChanges` all those changes are committed to the database, in a single operation using an internal database transaction. If you *don't* call `SaveChanges` you get "automatic" rollback when the DbContest gets disposed as no changes were saved

Comment: @KonradPsiukPG that's why DbContext doesn't have *any* kind of "sync" mechanism nor does it need one. Because it's *not* an in-memory database

Comment: @KonradPsiukPG in the scope of a *single* operation (whatever that means for your application), typically inside a `using` block, you create a new DbConext, do whatever you want with the data locally, and call `SaveChanges` right before the operation completes. This works in a disconnected way just like every other high-performance data access mechanism going back to VB6.

Comment: This is not a question, it's a request for work. Please post your actual research and attempts at solving the problem.

Comment: OK, When I disabled tracking, dbContext seems to pull data from DB every time, I guess I'll reformat the code to use "not tracked" entities. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EFCore contexts are designed to have short lives.  You shouldn't be opening a context and hanging onto it.

Open a new instance when you need to touch (pull or push) data.

Answer (score 1):

For your particular scenario, you can have a method in your app/webpage which fires periodically and call an API.

The API action calls a function which creates DbContext, queries for the tables/records which you want to refresh in the app/webpage and return the results.

If it is a windows forms app, then instead of calling API, you can directly call the function which reads from db.